# UIControlState.Normal is Unavailable

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swift3, xcode8

Previously for `UIButton` instances, you were able to pass in `UIControlState.Normal` for `setTitle` or `setImage`.  `.Normal` is no longer available, what should I use instead?

```
let btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
btn.setTitle("title", for: .Normal) // does not compile
```

<sup>(This is a canonical Q&A pair to prevent the flood of duplicate questions related to this `UIButton` and `UIControl` changes with iOS 10 and Swift 3)</sup>

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Swift 3 update:

It appears that Xcode 8/Swift 3 brought `UIControlState.normal` back:

```
public struct UIControlState : OptionSet {

    public init(rawValue: UInt)


    public static var normal: UIControlState { get }

    public static var highlighted: UIControlState { get } // used when UIControl isHighlighted is set

    public static var disabled: UIControlState { get }

    public static var selected: UIControlState { get } // flag usable by app (see below)

    @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    public static var focused: UIControlState { get } // Applicable only when the screen supports focus

    public static var application: UIControlState { get } // additional flags available for application use

    public static var reserved: UIControlState { get } // flags reserved for internal framework use
}
```

`UIControlState.Normal` has been renamed to `UIControlState.normal` and removed from the iOS SDK.  For "Normal" options, use an empty array to construct an empty option set.

```
let btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))

// Does not work
btn.setTitle("title", for: .Normal) // 'Normal' has been renamed to 'normal'
btn.setTitle("title", for: .normal) // 'normal' is unavailable: use [] to construct an empty option set

// Works
btn.setTitle("title", for: [])
```

Comment: Mhmm `[]` is most certainly the cleanest and most obvious way to do this. Glad Apple decided to do this for some reason /s. I hope this is just a beta sorta thing but it doesn't look like that.

Comment: When using Xcode 8.1, convertor give `UIControlState()` to substitute `.Normal`.

Comment: Make up your mind Apple!! normal, or .Normal????? You are more bipolar than my ex.

Comment: I'm on my 5th hour in converting this project from swift 2 to 3.  if a reasonable thought is to rebuild all of the code from scratch then you messed up.  unbelievable.  This wouldn't even be bad if they allowed swift 2 support on their latest xcode.

Comment: @JAL One week's not terrible for conversion!

Answer (score 2):

The `.Normal` is removed(iOS 10 DP1), you can use the `[]` or `UIControlState(rawValue: UInt(0))` to replace the `.Normal`, if you don't want to change codes all around(in case apple add it again or you don't like the `[]`), you can just add once this code

```
extension UIControlState {
    public static var Normal: UIControlState { return [] }
}
```

or

```
extension UIControlState {
    public static var Normal: UIControlState { return UIControlState(rawValue: UInt(0)) }
}
```

then all the `.Normal` work like before.

Comment: If you were to add those extensions, you should have a lower-case `n` to start `normal` to match the other values like `highlighted` and `selected`.

Comment: @GaryMakin Your right, but I provide this extension for the guy who doesn't want to `replace all` in files. because the original one is `.Normal` so I keep it `N` not `n`. I think who need to the `n` they just know how to change it. This is just an example and we all developer not common user, right?

Comment: `UIControlState()` is better than `UIControlState(rawValue:UInt(0))`. Practically, `normal` should be no state, so `normal` is removed.

Answer (score 2):

Apple brought back the normal control state in more recent versions of Xcode beta.  Upgrade to the most recent Xcode beta and use `.normal`.

Comment: Although this initializer is exposed through `OptionSetType`, I'm not sure I would recommend this approach.  Personally, I think `[]` is more readable, but this is valid nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**

Replace from

```
btn.setTitle("title", for: .Normal)
```

to

```
btn.setTitle("title", for: UIControl.State.normal)
```