# setTitle(_ title: String?, for state: UIControlState) where is .Normal state?

Tags: swift, swift3, ios10, uicontrolstate

I'm updating my app to Swift 3 with iOS10 on Xcode 8 
and I get an error on:

```
Btn.setTitle('str', forState: .Normal)
```

.Normal is not an enum type of UIControlState any more.
Which type of UIControlState should I use for this state?

Apple enum is now defined as

```
public struct UIControlState : OptionSet {

   public init(rawValue: UInt)


   public static var highlighted: UIControlState { get } // used when UIControl isHighlighted is set

   public static var disabled: UIControlState { get }

   public static var selected: UIControlState { get } // flag usable by app (see below)

   @available(iOS 9.0, *)
   public static var focused: UIControlState { get } // Applicable only when the screen supports focus

   public static var application: UIControlState { get } // additional flags available for application use

   public static var reserved: UIControlState { get } // flags reserved for internal framework use 
}
```

Comment: Did you try the "Convert to Latest Swift Syntax" option in Xcode? It should solve your problem automatically.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like any other option set:

```
button.setTitle("", for: [])
```

where `[]` stands for `.normal` (the value of `.normal` is `0`).

Note that we can use multiple states in one call:

```
button.setTitle("", for: [.selected, .disabled])
```

That's why `UIControlState` has been changed into an option set.

Comment: Or `UIControlState.Normal` .

Comment: @Dershowitz123 I decided to use the the newer syntax although I am not a big fan of `for:` over `forState:`.

Comment: Yeah your answer is right! I just wanted to let him know it can done this way also.

Comment: @Dershowitz123 Actually my answer was wrong. You have to use `[]` for `.normal`. `UIControlState.Normal` is not available any more in Swift 3.

Comment: You can use .normal

Comment: @JoeGinley Yes, I can use it now. It was not possible back in Swift 3, that's why this question appeared in the first place.

Comment: @Sulthan It has been available since Swift 3, look here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800342/uicontrolstate-normal-is-unavailable

Unless they kept changing it in Swift 3 from Xcode beta or something, maybe I didn't realize.

Comment: @JoeGinley Can't really remember which version was that :) In some version the `.normal` option was missing.