# How to toggle button text and colour in Xcode 10 - UIControl.State.normal missing

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to swift and watching a tutorial on how to toggle the background colour and text of a button when it is clicked.

The problem is, the background colour and text do not change when the button is clicked.

The function, which is identical to the instructor's and works on his laptop is :

```
func flipCard(withEmoji emoji: String, on button: UIButton){
    if button.currentTitle == emoji{
     button.setTitle("", for UIControl.State.normal)
     button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }else{
    button.setTitle(emoji, for UIControl.State.normal)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }

}
```

I call the function with:

```
@IBAction func callFlip(_ sender:UIButton){
   flipcard(withEmoji: "em", on: sender)
}
```

I have searched for a solution but they all seem to refer to older versions of Xcode and swift.

Nevertheless i have tried to to replace

`button.setTitle(emoji, for: UIControl.State.normal)`

with

`button.setTitle(emoji, for: UIControl.State(rawValue:UInt(0)))` and

`button.setTitle(emoji, for: [])` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37800343/2570277) with the same result :( . How can i get this to work please?

Im using Xcode 10.1 (10B61). Does the version of Xcode matter?

cheers

Comment: Is your `flipCard` method even called?

Comment: Yes I call it from an IBaction

Answer (score 0):

Tested this, with a button with title FlipColor and get the inverting effect.

```
 func flipCard(withEmoji emoji: String, on button: UIButton){
      if button.currentTitle == emoji {
           button.setTitle("", for: UIControl.State.normal)
           button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
           button.tintColor = .yellow
      }else{
           button.setTitle(emoji, for: UIControl.State.normal)
           button.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
           button.tintColor = .red
      }

 }

 @IBAction func flipMyColor(_ sender: UIButton) {

      flipCard(withEmoji : "FlipColor", on: sender)
 }
```

Comment: thanks for the response . i see you have added an extra line that changes the tintColor. Do you still get the inverting effect without that line? and what version of Xcode do you have? cheers

Comment: I tried to understand your intent, to flip color… But yes, it works without tintColor. As you set text to "", we just get a red rectangle with nothing inside. Version is Xcode 10.1. You should check that the button title is set correctly in IB (here, set as "FlipColor"), with correct uppercasing.